# are we able to edit default media player of Honeycomb?

Tags: android, video, media-player

I'd like to add some functionality inside of **default media player** for honeycomb without making any other class that using mediaPlayer package from Android, such as showing the information for particular video by swiping the screen, etc. Is that possible? if not, there's no other way to make my own class for the media player :(

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible: the default media player on Android can not be modified by third party code. If you want to build your own media player you can start by looking at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) and in the platform samples, but you will need to do significantly more work to get a fully functional media player.